# How to track lead generating products

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a website where we present our products, there is no price shown, no add-to-cart button, just photos and text.

We want to track form submissions by product. (product x => 32 form submissions, product y => 7 form submissions)

We have setup a gtag event with a goal in analytics to show us how many people used the contact form successfully with

```js
window.gtag('event', 'submit', {
   'event_category': 'form',
   'event_label': 'contact_form',
   'value': 1                   
})
```

I cannot find something specific for this in the google analytics events documentation

Answer (score 1):

Without being too complicated, why not just reorganize your events a little.

```
window.gtag('event', 'submit', {
   'event_category': 'contact form',
   'event_label': 'product x',
   'value': 1                   
})
```